# Accessing member of class from a callback after typeguard filtering

Tags: typescript, callback, type-conversion

TypeScript version 3.0.1

Please see this sample:

```
class Bar{
    public id ='bar';
}
function createABar():Bar|Error{
    return new Bar();
}

function check(){

    let aGlobal = createABar();

    if (aGlobal instanceof Bar){
        let aGlobal2=aGlobal;

        let arr=['one', 'bar', 'three'];

        let theAGlobalId=aGlobal.id;        // ts no complaints

        let exists = arr.find(i => i == aGlobal.id);  // ts Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Bar | Error'. 
        console.log(exists);        // it has been found (as expected)

                      // alternate syntax: 
        let exists2 = arr.find(function (i){return i == aGlobal.id});   // ts Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Bar | Error'. 

        let exists3 = arr.find(i => i == aGlobal2.id);   // ts no complaints
    }
}
check();
```

I am getting the error'Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Bar | Error'.' when accessing id from class Bar inside the callback of find.

It looks like in this case the type guard loses his effectiveness.

Assigning the "typeguarded" variable to another (aGlobal2) works

Is this to be expected?

By the way, I couldn't use the tag typeguard in this question (it doesn't exist and I have no reputation to create it, should it be created?)

Comment: Does `public id = 'bar'` still make it inaccessible?

Comment: @FortyTwo Yes, I will update the sample here.

Comment: Well ts compiler cannot infer it should be `Bar`. I would simply add a cast `arr.find(i => i === (<Bar>aGlobal).id);`

Answer (score 1):

Typeguards and flow analysis in general do not cross function boundaries. In your case the anonymous function you pass to `find` will not benefit from any of the guards that were done. The solution to use a local variable is probably the simplest and safest one.